# Dropdown menu won't show with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, dropdown

I'm following this [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar) from weSchools to make a dropdown menu in my navigation bar.

My problem is it won't show unless I remove the CSS property `overflow: hidden` from the `ul` class. This ruins the layout of the page and removes background colours etc.

I've tried `display: block` toggled on/off but the dropdown menu doesn't appear either way, as it does with the w3school tutorial.

I think there is maybe some problem with using a custom class `.sticky` rather than `ul` directly in the CSS, is it inheriting or not inheriting something?

Here is my HTML/CSS. I've gone over it multiple times to compare to the w3schools example and can't find a difference other than the `ul` tag. If I remove `.sticky` from the `ul` nav list then it loses formatting and affects another `ul` at the footer. So I need to define a custom class for this header nav list.

```css
.sticky {
    /*float: right;*/
    /*color: white;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

li {
    float: right;
    /*padding-right: 20px;*/
    /*padding-left: 20px;*/
    color: white;
}

li a, .dropBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-family: monospace;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropBtn {
    /*background-color: #454542;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /*border-radius: 10%;*/
    padding: 14px 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;*/
}

li a:active {
    /*background-color: deeppink;*/
    /*    add some transition here */
}
```

```html
<ul class="sticky">
    <li><a class="active" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropBtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:sticky;` from the selector, `sticky` is a keyword so I have changed that to `Links` for reference.

```css
.Links {
  /*float: right;*/
  /*color: white;*/
  list-style-type: none;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

li {
  float: right;
  /*padding-right: 20px;*/
  /*padding-left: 20px;*/
  color: white;
}

li a,
.dropBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropBtn {
  /*background-color: #454542;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*border-radius: 10%;*/
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="Links">
  <li><a class="active" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropBtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can it not be sticky and have an overflow at the same time?

Comment: Went to have dinner and see many answers! Yes, you can use `flex` for the `ul` and that should take care of it. coming to the overflow you just have to specify `height` and `overflow:auto;` so that you will have your scroll made.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be sticky ;)

```css
.sticky {
  /* float: right; */
  /* color: white; */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

li {
  float: right;
  /*padding-right: 20px;*/
  /*padding-left: 20px;*/
  color: white;
}

li a,
.dropBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropBtn {
  /*background-color: #454542;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*border-radius: 10%;*/
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;*/
}

li a:active {
  /*background-color: deeppink;*/
  /*    add some transition here */
}
```

```html
<ul class="sticky">
  <li><a class="active" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropBtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
      <a href="#">Item</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
</ul>

test <br> test <br> test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test
<br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test
<br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test
<br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are making the `li` elements `float: right`

The float property takes the element out of the normal flow.

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow.

So, your `ul` effectively don't have any height when rendered hence causing this issue. Just remove float from the `li` style rule and make it `display: inline-block`.

```css
.sticky {
    /*float: right;*/
    /*color: white;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
}

li a, .dropBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-family: monospace;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropBtn {
    /*background-color: #454542;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /*border-radius: 10%;*/
    padding: 14px 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;*/
}

li a:active {
    /*background-color: deeppink;*/
    /*    add some transition here */
}
```

```html
<ul class="sticky">
    <li><a class="active" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropBtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully fixed including the styling: https://jsfiddle.net/L9nw5et0/

```
.sticky {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

li {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

li a,
.dropBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropBtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff922;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```